# Can't Compile C# in Windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, windows-7, mono

I always loved game development but I never had a proper pc to start experimenting. I had a celeron cpu laptop with 2gb of ram. This is barely enough for windows 10 to boot! Now I got a pc that is just a little better that the previous laptop that I owned. It has a Pentium G2020 and 4gb DDR3 RAM. It ain't a beast but it is an upgrade. Well, I got it with Windows 7 Ultimate pre-installed and its doing pretty well, but I've tried Windows 10 and it was very, very, very slow.

So, I wanted to instal Visual Studio but after the installation nothing happened. I tried everything to start it up but I did nothing. No VS no c# Compiler. Now, don't get me wrong, there's a MONO compiler but it's in VS's path ("Not Starting"). I then downloaded Microsoft's .NET framework 4.8 and .NET framework Developer Pack 4.8 . But again, when I tried to compile a Hello World app in cmd by running csc helloworld.cs it said that csc isnt a command. If I'm doing anything wrong please correct me

I don't know what the solution could be, but I've already installed every Windows 7 Update. Reinstalling Windows or upgrading to Windows 10 isn't a choice

Thanks

Comment: Couple of things to check. In Control Panel, programs and features, is there anything related to Visual studio showing up? You should have Visual Studio Installer listed

Comment: No, I don't have it

Comment: You might have to "insist". Go back and try to download and re-run the Visual Studio 2019 Community installer (the installer name starts with vs_community )

Answer (score 0):

Man,:
Open VS,
Create new project,
Select console application.

Then put your hello world code to your main file, compile and run.

If "csc" is not recognized as a command then you have to add to environment variable "path" the path to "csc.exe".
Visual Studio is "integrated development environment" and you should make your projects without console compiling like you explained.

Comment: That might be a solution but in my case I can't even install Visual Studio